# Django TastyPie Patch to a Many-to-Many

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm trying to use TastyPie `Patch` to a many-to-many, but I get this error:

**"error_message": "Tastypie requires a Python-style path () to lazy load related resources. Only given 'SchemeResource'.",**

Why?

**The patch I'm making:**

```
/participant/84
POST: {"email":"test@test.com",  "schemes":{"id":"12", "schemes"}}
```

**Resource:**

```
class ParticipantResource(ModelResource):

    schemes = fields.ToManyField('SchemeResource', attribute='schemes', full=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Participant.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'participant'
        allowed_methods = ['post', 'get', 'put', 'patch']
```

**2nd Resource:**

```
class SchemeResource(ModelResource):

    user = fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'user', full=True)
    link = fields.ToOneField(SchemeLinkResource, 'link', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Scheme.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'scheme'
```

**Model:**

```
class Participant(models.Model):

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    mobile = PhoneNumberField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    schemes = models.ManyToManyField(Scheme)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use brackets such as

```
[]
```

around your schemes items (even if singular) when posting to a m2m field.

Request would then look like :

```
{"email":"test@test.com",  "schemes":[{"id":"12", "schemes"}]}
```

When you want to know what a request should look like, make a GET request on url/of/api/modelresource/schema/

If I recall correctly (and although you wrote "POST" in your request), PATCH request must have

```
{"objects": [...]}
```

enclosing the body.

**EDIT :**

Here's an example of what works for me :

**Resources :**

```
class VATCertificateResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = VATCertificate.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'vatcertificate'
        authorization = Authorization()

class InterventionResource(ModelResource):

    vatcertificates = fields.ToManyField('core.api.VATCertificateResource', 'vatcertificates',
                                     related_name='intervention', null=True, blank=True, full=True)
```

**Models :**

```
class VATCertificate(Document):
    intervention = models.ForeignKey(Intervention, related_name='vatcertificates', blank=True, null=True)

class Intervention(models.Model):
    pass
```

Hope this helps,

Regards,

Comment: Hi Ambroise, thanks for the response, unfortunately I get the same error with the brackets too.

Comment: I've edited my answer, maybe it'll give you some ideas on how to fix your issue... With it and an identical request format, I manage to patch the resource and its m2m objects. Good luck !

Comment: I'll give it a go, put I just noticed you are using a ForeignKey in your VATCertificate model note a ManyToManyField, how does this work as a many to many like that?

Comment: I'm displaying it in admin as inlines, the reverse relationfield is created in any case.